# Infinite expression 1/0. encountered - caused by precision?

Tags: machine-precision

[Planck's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) dependent on frequency rho is as follows:

```
   B[T_, h_, rho_, k_, c_] := (2 h rho^3)/c^2 1/(Exp[h rho/(T k)] - 1)
```

As you can see, the denominator can only be zero for rho = 0. All the rest are nonzero constants. Curiously if we try to plot it

```
Plot[B[5800, 6.626 10^-34, rho, 1.38 10^-23, 299792458], {rho, 
  0.1 10^-6, 3 10^-6}]
```

It will return  "Infinite expression 1/0. encountered" and the plot will be blank. In fact, substituting any value for rho appears to result in this error (out = ComplexInfinity). I have no experience with precision, but I don't see any other possible reason. Anyway to solve this?

Comment: when doing numerical calculations, it's better to work in dimensionless units, like here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2057/16 so as to avoid underflow/overflow problems. so if I were you I'd set $h=k_B=c=1$ and go from there

Comment: As @acl said, try **Plot[B[5, 1, rho, 1, 1], {rho, 0, 100}]** ... Plank's units

Comment: Also, not sure what you're doing but there is not much 5800K black-body radiation at 10^-6 Hertz. A better place to look might be around 10^15 Hz.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To understand what is going on, look at this:

```
N[b[5800, 6626 10^-37, rho, 138 10^-25, 299792458]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

look at the exponent in the second term in the denominator. If you put $\rho\approx 10^{-6}$, you're trying to calculate the difference between two numbers that are extremely close to each other, namely, between $1$ and $\exp(\alpha)$ with $\alpha\approx 10^{-21}$. So you run into numerical accuracy problems with machine numbers; see [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/) and at the end of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5582/16).

In general, when doing numerical calculations for physical problems, it's better to work in [dimensionless units](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2057/16), so as to avoid underflow/overflow problems. so if I were you I'd set $h=k_B=c=1$  (this amounts to a choice of units) and go from there.