# AccuracyGoal, PrecisionGoal, WorkingPrecision and NDSolve

Tags: numerics, arbitrary-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I'm trying to understand exactly what `WorkingPrecision`, `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` mean for the result of `NDSolve`.

I presume `WorkingPrecision` simply means the number of decimal places used internally by *Mathematica* at various points throughout the calculation on its scratchpad, and therefore essentially gives upper limit to what the accuracy/precision of final result can be.

Now I understand Accuracy/Precision somewhat in the lab sense (Accuracy is how close you are to the true value, Precision is how repeatable the value you get is in some sense; or to use the dartboard analogy-if you're near the bullseye that's accurate-if you hit the the outskirts in the same place 100 times that's precise but not accurate), but not sure I know how these correlate to the *Mathematica* concepts...

If I set `AccuracyGoal->3`, `PrecisionGoal->4` in `NDSolve`, what does that say about the function I get spat out? It looks like the definition on the help pages is that `AccuracyGoal` of 3 would mean 3 significant figures are correct, whereas `PrecisionGoal` of 4 would give 4 digits after the decimal are correct... e.g if the answer spat out is $89.7895$. What does it mean though in this case to say 3 significant figs are correct, but 4 digits after decimal place are also correct? Seems inconsistent (just a rule of thumb?).

The help pages also state:

> With `AccuracyGoal->a` and `PrecisionGoal->p`, *Mathematica* attempts to make the numerical error in a result of size be less than $10^{-a}+|x|10^{-p}$

Does this mean if I did have `AccuracyGoal->3`, `PrecisionGoal->4` and `NDSolve` spat out $89.7895$ the numerical error would be $10^{-3}+89.7895\cdot 10^{-4}=0.0997895$ ? so my answer is really $89.7895\pm 0.0997895$ ? or is there a different definition of numerical error here?

Thanks for any clarifications.

Comment: there is an answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9018/16) that is related (but does not answer your particular question)

Comment: This is a very nice question!

Answer (score 9):

Regarding your last question: in the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindRoot.html) for `FindRoot` it says that

> FindRoot continues until either of the goals specified by AccuracyGoal or PrecisionGoal is achieved.

The same thing is mentioned in the docs for `NMinimize`.

On the other hand, the docs for `NDSolve` say

> AccuracyGoal effectively specifies the absolute local error allowed at each step in finding a solution, while PrecisionGoal specifies the relative local error.

and also

> NDSolve adapts its step size so that the estimated error in the solution is just within the tolerances specified by PrecisionGoal and AccuracyGoal.

So we are reduced to trying to work out whether "and" really means "and" in which case it'll try to satisfy both, or if it behaves like `FindRoot`.

(this is more of a comment than an answer, but it's too long)

Comment: I'll erase this in an hour or so when I know that you have seen it (as I said it's an overlong comment)

Comment: Don't delete it! I found it very educational, even if it does not answer the question explicitly.

Comment: Yes this is nice to know, thanks, but still wondering about a lot of things, if anyone out there can say more.