# Use of AccuracyGoal & MachinePrecision in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy

I just learned about the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standard) and it seems like a very useful tool. For example, to find an analytic solution to

$$
\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1-e^{-x} (x+1)}{\left(e^x-1\right) \left(e^{-x}+e^x\right) x} \, dx,
$$

one can solve it numerically to obtain

```
0.156595806752698829513363962452
```

and submit this to the Calculator to obtain the analytic expression

$$
-\frac{\gamma }{2}+\frac{\pi }{8}-\frac{1}{4} 3 \log (2)+\frac{\log (\pi )}{2}.
$$

([Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1816901/evaluate-int-0-infty-frac1-e-x1x-xex-1exe-xdx))

However, I'm having trouble reproducing this result, i.e., using `NIntegrate` with the right settings for `WorkingPrecision`, `AccuracyGoal`, and `PrecisionGoal` to obtain the numerical result above.

I eventually found that

```
NIntegrate[(1 - Exp[-x] (1 + x))/(x (Exp[x] - 1) (Exp[x] + Exp[-x])), 
    {x, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 40, AccuracyGoal -> 25]
```

yielded

```
0.1565958067526988295133639624516335266315,
```

which the Calculator can't find an analytic form for, but if I chop off the last several digits and submit instead

```
0.1565958067526988295133639624516335
```

then the Calculator finds the correct analytic expression.

This took a lot of guess-and-check, and I would like to know if there is a more sure-fire way to get a bunch of digits out of `NIntegrate` to look up analytic expressions like this.

(I've read the docs on `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal` as well as [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9161/accuracygoal-precisiongoal-workingprecision-and-ndsolve) MSE link.)

Comment: As it turns out, your result is accurate to 34 or so digits when compared to `-EulerGamma/2 + π/8 - 3 Log[2]/4 + Log[π]/2`. Anyway: `Method -> "DoubleExponential"` gives good results for integrals like this. A rule of thumb you can use is that you can set `AccuracyGoal` up to ten less than the `WorkingPrecision` setting. Thus, you could try `SetPrecision[
 NIntegrate[(1 - Exp[-x] (1 + x))/(2 x (Exp[x] - 1) Cosh[x]), {x, 0, ∞}, AccuracyGoal -> 35, Method -> "DoubleExponential", WorkingPrecision -> 45], 35]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough comment! I'd be happy to consider this an answer if you feel like submitting it as one.