# Solution of Riccati equation of y'[z]==R(z) y(z)^2+Q(z) y(z)+P(z) type

Tags: differential-equations

I have seen that for Riccati equation the solution can be done by

```
DSolve[y'[z] == P[z] + Q[z] y[z] + R[z] y[z]^2, y[z], z]
```

but for my case mathematica fails to compute it.
I am trying this

```
DSolve[y'[x] + ((2.248*10^12)/x^2) (y[x])^2 - (22.48/x^2) y[x] - 
23.3455*10^6 x Exp[-2x] == 0, y[x], x]
```

The Output Shows
  RowReduce::luc
.After doing this

```
result[x_] = y[x] /. NDSolve[{y'[x] == -(2.24794*10^12 ((y[x]^2 - 
y[x]/10^11 - ((0.000010385 x^3)/E^(2 x)))/x^2)), 
y[10] == 10^-5.3}, y[x], {x, 10, 100}][[1]]
LogPlot[result[x], {x, 10, 100}, 
PlotRange -> {{10, 100}, {10^-15, 10^-4}}]
```

I get this[image: Y vs X plot(Not expected this)]

Comment: Analytical solving seems impossible.

Comment: But when i am trying it by giving a boundary condition and suitable range it gives some solutions but it is not even near my expectation

Comment: @DarkKnight45 Example? -- Part of the problem may be the scale of the constants, tho' I think Mariusz is probably right...

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have added my scales and also tried to plot it but failed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Long comment about the `NDSolve` example:*

The default `AccuracyGoal` is half working precision or around `8` for `MachinePrecision`.  That means that errors below `10^-8` are treated as acceptable (equivalent to zero).  When the value of the solution remains below `10^-8` for a long period, error control basically is turned off, and the solution can bounce around above and below zero.  Raising `AccuracyGoal` can help.

```
result[x_] = 
  y[x] /. NDSolve[{y'[] == -(2.24794*10^12 ((y[x]^2 - 
              y[x]/10^11 - ((0.000010385 x^3)/E^(2 x)))/x^2)), 
      y[10] == 10^-5.3}, y[x], {x, 10, 100}, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 16][[1]];
LogPlot[result[x], {x, 10, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> {{10, 100}, {10^-15, 10^-4}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a Lot.You got  it correctly

Comment: In mathematica changing this accuracy goal slightly changes the results is such randomness  permissible in scientific publication

Comment: @DarkKnight45 It should be, but I suppose it depends on what the editors/reviews understand about numerical analysis and *Mathematica*.  With most numerical ODE solvers, each step incurs an error, in which the compute solution steps off the current solution curve onto another that is "near by."  How near by depends on the step size.  The smaller the step, the smaller the maximum error. As the step size decreases, the "randomness" should go away and the computed solution should converge to a stable result.  `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` are one way for the user to control the step size.

Comment: Here's a simple example of how decreasing step size eventually converges toward the exact solution $y = e^{-x}$: `Table[
 ListLinePlot[
  NDSolveValue[{y'[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 60}, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"}, 
   StartingStepSize -> 1.5^k],
  InterpolationOrder -> 3, PlotLabel -> Row[{"Step size ", 1.5^k}]],
 {k, 4, -1, -1}]`

Comment: @DarkKnight45 For further discussion, see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveVectorNorm.html, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9161/accuracygoal-precisiongoal-workingprecision-and-ndsolve, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118249/is-manual-adjustment-of-accuracygoal-and-precisiongoal-useless, and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138634/4999