# DSolve returns incomplete solution

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve this differential equation with `DSolve`:

$$\ddot{y}(t) = \frac{c-t\,a}{\sqrt{(c-t\,a)^2+(d-t\,b)^2}}$$

This is the command I used:

```
DSolve[y''[t] == (c - t*a)/Sqrt[(c - t*a)^2 + (d - t*b)^2], y[t], t]
```

The solution is not pretty, but after using `FullSimplify`, I get:

[image]

Now the problem is that for $t = 0$ I should get $y(t=0) = C[1]$ but instead I get this:

[image]

In addition I integrated the function numericaly and for

```
a = -0.067188179319158187
b = -0.49514533746770106
c = -0.33442811816228007
d = -2.0301335303268586
t = 8.0973579559937114
```

with the initial values

```
c[1] = 10.0
c[2] = -2.0
```

The function should be zero, but that is also not true. I am not sure if I made a mistake or if it is a problem with `DSolve`; my best guess would be that because the solution to differential quations are always definite integrals. I would need to incorporate the upper and lower bounds similar to what is mentioned in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85312/dsolve-returns-a-wrong-solution?newreg=bbf3351d8348490d8a2080dd108ad351) thread, However. I don't know how I would do that.

It would be great if someone could help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issued raised is not really a problem; it is arises from the OP's misunderstanding of the result returned by Mathematica.

Comment: Try `DSolve[{y''[t] == (c - t*a)/Sqrt[(c - t*a)^2 + (d - t*b)^2], 
  y[0] == y0, y'[0] == v0}, y[t], t]` and see if you agree with the solution.

Comment: Thank you that's the solution! But shouldn't it work with the arbitrary constants the same way? Sorry if that's off topic.

Comment: @Ganymed_ What the user who answered below was saying is that unless you impose what `y[0]` is as a constraint, any constant value will satisfy the equation and therefore is a valid solution.

Answer (score 3):

Since

```
y[0] /. 
  C[1] -> 
    (-(1/(a^2 + b^2)^(3/2)))*
         (-((b*(b*c - a*d)*Sqrt[c^2 + d^2])/Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]) + 
         (a*(a*c + b*d)*Sqrt[c^2 + d^2])/(2*Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]) - 
         (a*((-b)*c + a*d)^2*Log[(-a)*c - b*d + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]*
            Sqrt[c^2 + d^2]])/(2*(a - I*b)*(a + I*b)) + 
         (b*(b*c - a*d)*((-a)*c - b*d)*
            Log[(-a)*c - b*d + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]*Sqrt[c^2 + d^2]])/(a^2 + b^2))
```

gives 0. there is nothing wrong with your result. Two solutions to a differential equation can always differ by an arbitrary constant.

Comment: Yes, `c[1]` and `c[2]` are the arbitrary constants but if $\ddot{y}(t)$ is the acceleration of a point then `c[1]` is the initial position, `c[2]` the initial velocity and $t$ the elapsed time. So I expect that my point is at `c[1]` at $t = 0$.